# REporting Service Rotating The Text

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a Reporting Service (SQL Server 2005) 
I have a text, lets say `Hello World`
I want to write it in

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

format. I used the `Writing Mode` property of Text Box and i also tried other ways but i didn't achieve the right format. Is there any expression or something else that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me setting the WritingMode to "tb-rl" and setting the width of the text box appropriately.

Are you relying on auto size or something?